# How to expose stored procedure from database for apicontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017

I'm struggling to understand the recommended way of exposing a stored procedure using EF, and whether there's a benefit in doing so.

I've implemented a database-first code to wrap the stored procedure, which generated something like the following within the context:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<PWB_P_GetAvailableOfferings_Result> PWB_P_GetAvailableOfferings(Nullable<int> productID, Nullable<System.DateTime> purchaseDate, Nullable<int> accountID, Nullable<int> locationID)
{
        var productIDParameter = productID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("ProductID", productID) :
            new ObjectParameter("ProductID", typeof(int));

        var purchaseDateParameter = purchaseDate.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("PurchaseDate", purchaseDate) :
            new ObjectParameter("PurchaseDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

        var accountIDParameter = accountID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("AccountID", accountID) :
            new ObjectParameter("AccountID", typeof(int));

        var locationIDParameter = locationID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("LocationID", locationID) :
            new ObjectParameter("LocationID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<PWB_P_GetAvailableOfferings_Result>("PWB_P_GetAvailableOfferings", productIDParameter, purchaseDateParameter, accountIDParameter, locationIDParameter);
    }
```

I then created a controller for it:

```
public class AvailableOfferingsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ProductConfigurationContext _repository =
        new ProductConfigurationContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ObjectResult<PwbPGetAvailableOfferingsResult> Get( int? productId, int? segmentId, int? channelId, int? salesRegionId, bool? returnExpiredOfferings, int? accountId)
    {
        return _repository.PWB_P_GetProductOfferings(productId, segmentId, channelId, salesRegionId, returnExpiredOfferings, accountId);
    }
}
```

My startup code:

```
public static class Startup
{
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder.Use(typeof(NotFoundMiddleware));

        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

My controller is unresponsive. I'm sending a GET request against https://myservice/AvailableOfferings/ and getting timeouts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and what do you find when you use your debugger?

Comment: oh, also, is this debugging? do you have an HTTPs endpoint you are debugging against? or is it hosted on HTTP?

Comment: @KeithNicholas the debugger is not attaching at all. i am doing it against https, i have another project in the same solution that works without issue, it's also EF6, but it's doing ODataController, not ApiController, and  it's querying entities (tables)., not a sproc

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I would recommend adding logs to identify the root cause, also how much time does your store proc takes to execute, as there may be an issue where the stored procedure takes time greater than response timeout of the API.